# Switch USB OTG device between different apps without unplugging the device (Android)

Tags: android, usb, usb-otg

I currently have a problem with one specific scenario when using my USB device (which happens to be a USB MIDI controller, i.e. musical keyboard), with my Android phone (OS version 5.0.1) via USB OTG. I am competent with Android programming, so the solution may be a consumer-oriented solution or it may be a programmer-oriented solution (i.e. if someone points me in the right direction, I am able write an app to fix the problem - but if that is not necessary then all the better).

I am able to connect the device (a Korg MicroKEY 61), and it is recognised by numerous apps, such as "MIDI Commander" and "MicroKeyPlayer". I am able to play the keyboard and get sounds out of it using MicroKeyPlayer. There is no problem there.

However, this only works when the app in question has been selected from the menu that appears when you plug in the device - the menu that says "Choose an app for the USB device". When you select an app from this menu, it appears that the selected app is granted an unlimited permission to use the USB device, until it is unplugged. However, when it is unplugged, it loses the permission.

The problem is that there appears to be no way to grant permission to any other apps without unplugging the device, plugging it back in again, and selecting the new app from the "Choose an app..." menu. You are then back in the same boat - only one app may have access to the device until it is unplugged.

This is a problem because when the device is unplugged, its MIDI state is lost, meaning that e.g. the assignment of the modulation wheel's function goes back to the default. This means that I cannot e.g. set the modulation wheel as a "Sustain pedal" control in MIDI Commander, and then switch to MicroKeyPlayer to play the keyboard with the modulation wheel on that setting.

I know that I could use an external powered hub to keep the device alive while the phone is unplugged, but it makes for a more tangle-prone and less convenient rig (more stuff to carry when moving it around the house, etc.), and anyway in principle I should not have to use one. (Also I don't happen to have one to hand at the moment. And it may increase latency.)

I think it is most probable that the app developers are technically at fault - they should be checking for the permission with UsbManager.hasPermission(), and dynamically acquiring the permission if necessary using UsbManager.requestPermission(), instead of simply assuming that they have it.

However, I am wondering whether there could be a way around this. Perhaps there is some way to programmatically give USB permission to another app? Or perhaps there is some Intent that could be triggered to bring up the "Choose an app..." menu again without unplugging the device?

Can anyone with a better understanding of Android USB confirm whether I am looking at this the right way? Is the only solution to contact the apps' developers?